# Is it possible to define a type that refers to a type parameter from another line?

Tags: typescript

Using the `Promise` type as an example:

```
interface Promise<T> {
  then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
    onfulfilled?:
      | ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>)
      | undefined
      | null,
    onrejected?:
      | ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>)
      | undefined
      | null
  ): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;

  catch<TResult = never>(
    onrejected?:
      | ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>)
      | undefined
      | null
  ): Promise<T | TResult>;
}
```

This code might look cleaner if the `onfulfilled` and/or `onrejected` types were defined on a separate line. This doesn't compile, but here's what it might look like:

```
interface Promise<T> {
  type OnFulfilled = 
      | ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>)
      | undefined
      | null
  type OnRejected =
      | ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>)
      | undefined
      | null

  then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
    onfulfilled?: OnFulfilled,
    onrejected?: OnRejected
  ): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;

  catch<TResult = never>(
    onrejected?: OnRejected
  ): Promise<T | TResult>;
}
```

Is it possible to write types *like* this, to improve type readability?

Comment: What makes you say that this code might look cleaner if the types were defined on a separate line? The first block looks perfectly readable? The only questionable part is where things aren't being called by their name: `TResult1` doesn't tell you anything about what it actually _is_, but structure wise this looks fine?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I guess it's a bad example if you feel it looked better before, but I'm more interested in TS syntax.

Comment: Then you may have to find a different example because I might be missing your question for the example you're giving. But I'd question the underlying motivation: what TS looks like is basically irrelevant, as long as your tooling can _surface_ the typing in a way that lets you work with it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well, what about similar code where `onrejected`'s type is so long it distracts from the function signature?

Comment: You'd really have to give me an example, because that sounds like something you'd get from someone who's new to typescript and improperly modeled their types.

Comment: Without [ms/TS#41470](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41470) or similar (like [ms/TS#23188](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23188)) this is not currently possible.  The closest you can get now is to define a separate type with more generics than you'd like, and use them, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/weydVw). Does that fully address the question? If so I will write up a full answer post; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It does. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to create "local" or "inline" [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) this way.  There are several open feature requests asking for support for this; [microsoft/TypeScript#41470](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41470) proposes the same syntax you're using, while [microsoft/TypeScript#23188](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23188) proposes a different syntax which would have the same effect.  Until and unless such features are implemented, you'll have to work around it.

The closest you can get with TypeScript as of TS5.2 is to just create regular non-local, non-inline, separate type aliases, and give them [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) parameters to pass types which are now out of scope.  Like this, for example:

```
type OnFulfilled<T, R> =
    ((value: T) => R | PromiseLike<R>) | undefined | null;

type OnRejected<R> =
    ((reason: any) => R | PromiseLike<R>) | undefined | null;

interface Promise<T> {
    then<R1 = T, R2 = never>(
        onfulfilled?: OnFulfilled<T, R1>,
        onrejected?: OnRejected<R2>
    ): Promise<R1 | R2>;
    catch<R = never>(
        onrejected?: OnRejected<R>
    ): Promise<T | R>;
}
```

It's not the same, especially since you are now introducing new types in the same namespace.  For ambient types like `Promise<T>`, doing this pollutes the global namespace and possibly interferes with user-defined types.  But depending on the use case it might be a viable solution.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANNSDeAoJukBcBPGZAeWADEBXAGwDMBLGmiAEwB4AVAGiQCUAfEgC8OPOIAUEgG4gaVCAC4knAJQihfJAB8kABQBOAezAMoEADIMA1hHaD1uqsFYRGwNjqTBaNANxiuEQkSOR8EABWEPD4bPZCouKSEgYQIFBGwMogwITqwppehiZmljZ2Dl7Oru6euj7MAYFIDMCxBnQIyMWm5lxC2El4+AAWEMD2AIwiKrx8AEwzHtIQBgISzUO4mXS0jMxsAPzK5NT0TCwcPPyTAtybW5mpUTFHJ8DhL7EcCwIPuKplD1SlMvL8AlskPAQPh4CN7EsICs1htIeInpFot9jqEPpjXj8-pDAfpjL07JwwQIIXgAL5YWlAA)